# Usage of てくる in Motion of Object

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions

I have a doubt in regard to the use of てくる, while marking motion of an object.

Among other things, てくる can be used to mark motion of an object, and the fact that you received that motion.

E.g. 田中さんが手紙を送ってきた (Tanaka-san sent me a letter and I received it)

So, my question is, can any verb be used, with this てくる, or only verbs which indicate a sense of motion can be used:

As, in お母さんがシャツを買ってきた (Can mean, my mother bought shirt, and I received it), or お母さんが本を読んできた (My mother read the story, and I received it (i.e. listened it).

Also, can てくれる be used for verbs (which do not have inherent sense of direction) these to use of てきた. Like お母さんが私にシャツを買ってくれてきた、and お母さんが本を読んでくれてきた.

My second question is, does the object need to be tangible in nature, can it be abstract things like an idea, words etc. E.g. 君の考えを聞いてきた

Lastly, I want to just ask you about this example sentence that I read somewhere - "E.g. 田中さんが手紙を送ってきた". Over here is 私に implied?, or does in this usage we only talk about the act that is done by the person e.g. like 友達は長い手紙を書いてきた.

ありがとうございます. Sorry for the big question. でも、教えてください

Answer (score 3, accepted):

てくる is divided to て(and) 来る(come).
So, Basically, てくる means some action and come (to me, here or back here).

If directly translated,

> お母さんがシャツを買ってきた。
> My mother bought a shirt and came here/back here with the shirt. (not sure for who)

Just 買った means "My mother bought a shirt" (not sure where she is now and not sure for who).

くれてきた。 is something wrong.
Instead, we use きてくれた

> お母さんがシャツを買ってきてくれた。
> My mother bought a shirt and came to me and gave it to me. (Directly translated)
> My mother bought a shirt for me. (Translated naturally)
> 買って(buy) + きて(come) + くれた(give)

So, the order of 買って + くれて + きた is wrong.
You cannot give something to someone directly without coming.

Also, 読んで + くれて + きた is wrong because 読んでくれた(read a book for me) and come, is weird, right?

By the way, the correct order, 読んで + きて + くれた is very strange, but can be used in a rare situation.
For example:

> 母が図書館に行って本を読んできてくれた。
> 　(I have to read a book and write an essay as homework, but) my mother read the book in a library and came back here (and maybe writes the essay for me).

However!
This is a very difficult point in Japanese, but 送ってきた is not 送って(sent and) きた(came here).
This means just "sent it to you".
I guess the reason is as below.
When you write a letter to someone and send it, Japanese thought he/she is in the letter or his/her soul/feeling is in the letter. It means that you/your feeling literally comes to me riding on the letter like a train, bus or airplane.
So, おくってきた can be 送って(you sent it to me and) きた(your soul/feeling comes to me)
Now, we use 送ってきた as "sent it to me/you" although it is not a letter, but it is an email or even a gift box.

However, 送ってきた also can be "send + come here".
For example, You asked someone (her) to send your mail to someone, and then she went to a post office and came back.
She would say "I sent it to him" translated as "送ってきた".
This is "send + come". I think this case is occasional.

So, "送ってきた" can have both nuances. "send it to someone and receive" or "send + come here"
You need to judge from the context...

So, let me answer your three questions.

1. can any verb be used?
   Basically, you can use with any verb, but some words should be weird.
   For example, 来る(come) means already "come", so if you use てくる with 来る, it is "来てくる", that is come and come. It is weird.
2. Can use with abstract verb.
   As I mentioned "読んできてくれた", you can use though it depends on situation.
   So, 君の考えを聞いてきた can be used.
3. Whom did someone send it? in the case that "田中さんが手紙を送ってきた"
   It should be the person who said "田中さんが手紙を送ってきた", that is 私.
   However, in the following situation like question sentence, the object is not 私:

> A: 田中さんから手紙を受け取った。
> B: 田中さんが送ってきたの！？
> A: I received a letter from Tanaka-san.
> B: Tanaka-san send it to you!?

Anyway, the object should be obvious in the context.

I am sorry that this answer is so long, but it is difficult and good questions.

Note: See the comments to get more detailed answer

Comment: ありがとう 私は法科大学の年次の試験が２９日まであります ごめなさい. So I was not able to reply. I got what you were saying. However, I am not able to understand one point, which is, since 送ってきた, shows that the person has received it, can other verbs show to like 買う 読む among others when use with てくる or てきてくれる show that the other person received it? and not the fact that you are trying to say that he came and did that verb. Like, in your answer for 読んできてくれた, you said that she came back and did something.

Comment: (Contd...) However, what I wanted to ask was, can it simply mean that she read something to me and I received (listened) to it, just like in case of 送ってきた?

Comment: 読む or 買う with てくる is not same as 送る with てくる.

"読んでくれた" means "she read something to me and I listened to it". "読んできた" means "she read something (for herself) and came here." And, as I mentioned, "読んできてくれた" is very strange...though it depends on situation. If I heard that, I would guess she might have done something for you. But, at least, I have never seen the situation...  
 
"買ってきた"  is "She bought something and she came back." And "買ってきてくれた" is very common. We often use it.

Comment: 送ってきた means just "send it to someone". We are not sure if she came or not.  

So, it is not same as "読む" or ”買う”.

Do this answer your question?
By the way, Never mind about your late reply. I don't mind at all. Besides, I hope you will pass the exam in the law school.

Comment: So we can say that the "i received it" nuance that exists in 送ってきた, does not apply to all verbs when they are used with subsidiary てくる. も一つだけ、while I was reading i saw that it worked with 書くas well, like 手紙を書いてきた. So can you please tell me how it worked with 書く and not with others (as in what do Japanese (you all) think while using this てくる in sentences to make the nuance of "i received it" like you explained it with 送る. 教えてください！

Comment: Yes. However, please note "送ってきた" also does not always have "received it" nuance. I am sorry for my lack of explanation. For example, You asked someone (her) to send your mail to someone, and then she went to a post office and came back. She would say "I sent it to him" translated as "送ってきた". This is "send + come". I think this case is occasional, but can be happened.

Comment: “手紙を書いてきた” can have two meanings. It depends on situation. The first case is literally “wrote letter + came here”.  The second case is “手紙を書いて送ってきた”.  “送って” is omitted/skipped. In general, A letter is sent to someone. Of course, you can give it to someone directly, but you can guess it was sent to her. For example, You and she are talking. She is popular with boys and often gets love letters directly or indirectly. Then, she said “彼が手紙を書いてきた”. You would understand that he came and directly give it to her or he sent it to her.

Comment: In another case, If she said “レポートを書いてきた”, what do you think? I would definitely understand that she made/wrote a report and came here, but we are not sure this has “I received it” nuance or not.   
If I was a professor and she was a student, maybe means “I received it”, but if I was a friend of her, maybe means “A professor would receive it”.

Comment: So, either way, you need to figure out the meaning / nuance from the context, unfortunately...

Comment: ありがとうfor detailed reply. Kay-san can one say that for those verbs in which 送って can be used just like with 書く - which means/has the nuance that I received the letter? E.g. will it be true with お母さんがシャツを買ってきた . I received the shirt? ごめんなさい、私はたくさん質問をしました

Comment: Not sure "I received the shirt" because てくる basically has a nuance "and + come". "送ってくる" is an exception case. ”書いてくる” also basically means "write + come". "手紙" is an exception case. Letter is supposed to be sent. "手紙を書く" implies "誰かに送る", "send it to someone."

"買ってきた" means just "bought and came here". we are not sure for whom. we would guess it from the context. By the way, if she says "買ってきてくれた", it clealy means "I received it."

Comment: All てくる can have a nuance "I received it." because we are not sure for whom from the only sentence. If you want to know "for whom", you need to guess from the context or ask her/him thought we can guess for whom from the context in the most case.

Even in English, for example, when your mother/father bought a bread, milk, meet and so on, you would guess those are for your family though she/he did not say "for us". I mean, we, japanese just tends to omit "for whom" although it is not completely clear. お気になさらず納得できるまで質問してくださいね。（Never mind. Feel free to ask me until you are convinced.)

Comment: 最後の質問, I got what you tried to say about feelings (came) in that 送ってきた. The てくる in 買ってきてくれた, was actually 3 verbs that were conjoined that is to say (verb buy + verb came (Physically and she didn't send it) + verb gave (and thats how I received it) and it wasn't that てくる worked as a subsidiary. However, can I use verbs that can be conjoined with 送る and then add てくる the nuance of i received. 買う like, お母さんがシャツを買って送ってきた. (My mother bought shirt, and sent it (having the nuance i received it) or, should the sentence be divided, お母さんがシャツを買って、送ってきた. 本当に日本語が中々素晴らしくて面白いです。

Comment: Regarding "買ってきてくれた", you are collect. Besides, "てくる" and ”てくれる” is different. The former is "and come", but the latter means "and give". "くる（来る）" has a lot of conjugated form and very complicated.. 
I think this page is helpful to understand "来る（くる）"  https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E7%94%A8%E8%A8%80/%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-7-%E3%82%AB%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8-%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Regarding your question, you can say both, and we can guess your mother would bought and sent it to you for you.
If you would like to clearly show "I received it", you may be able to use "お母さんがシャツを買って（、）送ってきてくれた。" . I prefer this sentence in such a case.
If you were japanese and you said "お母さんがシャツを買って送ってきた", I would feel you don't like the shirt and thank her very well.  
By the way, you can also say "お母さんがシャツを買って送ってくれた(sent and gave)。”
In this case, we are not sure if it arrived and you ALREADY received it or not though it is clear that it is for you.

Comment: Yes. I guess Japanese is really different from English, difficult and interesting.
Well, I am still not good at English very much..(English is also difficult and interesting for me)

Comment: ありがとうございます、I finally got !. Thanks for the detailed explanation, and I also got your "feelings came" point in てくる, when it is used with 送る

Comment: You're welcome! I am very glad if it was helpful. 頑張ってくださいね。